# How to "Push" or if pushed route in pop stack "Pop" selectively in go router?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I want to pop or push depending on whether the page is in the pop stack or not.
For example;

*We have an 3 screen. Home Screen, Profile Screen, Info Screen.

*In profile screen we have a "Back to home screen button".

if user on Profile Screen come from Home screen i want to pop.

if user on Profile Screen come from Info screen i want to push Home Screen.

Like;

```
context.popOrPush(route);
```

How can i do that?

Comment: both pages navigate to home by pushing the route ?

Comment: pushing route causes the screen to lose its state.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `context.go(homeScreenRoute)`

or check the `GoRouterState.of(context)` `path` field to find out if you have Home screen in your stack and do what you want to do